# Keras Model Scoring

Tags: deep-learning, keras, text-classification

I have built a DL model for sentiment classification using Keras library and when I predict the scores of sentences using function model.predict() I get a probability score. I'd like to know if we need to set .5 as the threshold in deciding binary class??

Comment: unfortunately, if you dont have a specific programming question, we have to close this as not being specific (too broad).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think this question is already specific. I want to know if Keras uses 0.5 as the probability threshold while deciding binary class 1. I'm not sure how I can make this more detailed

Answer (score 0):

I learnt that we can use the function

> model.predict_classes(X)

to predict the classes directly. Surprisingly I could not find it in the official API reference.
https://keras.io/models/model/